# Yii2 change locale formats

Tags: internationalization, formatting, locale, yii2

I am migrating from Yii 1.x to Yii2.
In Yii 1.x you could define/change the localized formats in a file (sth like `/app/i18n/en.php`), where you could set all your desired formats, which you could later use.
Now in Yii2 this is gone?

I have 4 languages, each one has different settings. What am i supposed to do if I need a new formatting function?
E.g. I want to make a format for prices in a shop, in each lang differently

```
DE - 1.234,56
EN - 1,234.567
SK - 1234,5
CZ - 1 234,5678
```

So I create a new formatter function `Yii::$app->formatter->asPrice(1234.567890)`.

Do I have to program a `switch` inside the function, and check for the language? That would be very inconvenient, and a lot of duplicity if I need more such functions. And if I had a new language later,  I would have to adjust all such functions with a new `case`.
There must be a better solution. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I think you guys did not get my problem.. I know I can set the locale, and use the asDecimal or similar function. But the problem is that I cannot specifically customize the formatting options - it automatically takes the format defined in the intl PHP extension. I need the possiblity to specifically customize these formats. Maybe e.g. the default for EN is 2 decimals, but I need 3. Where can I set this?

Answer (score 3):

[In Yii2 official documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-formatter.html):

You can use as below:

```
Yii::$app->formatter->locale = 'en-US';
echo Yii::$app->formatter->asDate('2014-01-01'); // output: January 1, 2014
Yii::$app->formatter->locale = 'de-DE';
echo Yii::$app->formatter->asDate('2014-01-01'); // output: 1. Januar 2014
Yii::$app->formatter->locale = 'ru-RU';
echo Yii::$app->formatter->asDate('2014-01-01'); // output: 1 января 2014 г.
```

So if you have table with language you can set locale there and in main layout define "Yii::$app->formatter->locale = $lang->locale" where $lang is object of Language model(class) matching current language.

Comment: I think you did not get my problem.. I know I can set the locale, and use the asDate function. But the problem is that I cannot specifically customize the formatting options - it automatically takes some format according to the Intl PHP extension and the locale. I need the possiblity to specifically customize the formats

Comment: Now it's clear, How about create separate config file with locale settings let say _locale.php based on selected language choose locale settings. Add add all needful formats `'formatter' => [
        'dateFormat' => 'dd.MM.yyyy',
        'decimalSeparator' => ',',
        'thousandSeparator' => ' ',
        'currencyCode' => 'EUR',
   ],`  and merge with \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge() method main and _locale files. I haven't used before like this but it's just as version.

Comment: hm, that seems like a relatively good idea to go for. But as I understand it, there is no default option to change this then..

Comment: hm, but the problem now is, when to do this.. in the config I don't know the current language yet...

Comment: How about get language from session? If you store language in session.

Comment: I have done it that way now, that I extended the `Formatter`, and added the loading of the special config into the `init()` function.

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you want to use asDecimal?

```
echo Yii::$app->formatter->asDecimal(1234.5678);

DE - 1.234,568
EN - 1,234.568
SK - 1 234,568
CZ - 1 234,568
```

Or you may try something like:

```
    private $_priceDecimals = [ 'de_DE' => 2, 'en_EN' => 3, 'sk_SK' => 1, 'cz_CZ' => 4];

    public function asPrice($value)
    {
        return $this->asDecimal( 
            $value, 
            isset($this->_priceDecimals[$this->locale]) ? $this->_priceDecimals[$this->locale] : null
        );
    }
```

Comment: please see my update - the problem is that asDecimal takes some format, which I need to change